# How to minify and cache javascript and css that is returned in response to a Rails 4.2 controller action

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

My application has a javascript widget that external applications can use. The widget is served from a call to a controller action in Rails 4.2. Currently I have the javascript and the necessary css under `app/views/something.js.erb` and `app/views/something.css`.

These are begin served up correctly. But now I need to provide caching support and minify them. Rails 4.2 does not support this. What is the workaround?

Comment: Change perform_caching to true in **production.rb**, `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`. Check [this](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/some-tips-for-caching-javascript-and-css-in-rails/) for more examples.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html says that action caching has been removed from Rails 4

Comment: Also I want to minify the javascript,  it is rather long.

Comment: basic caching is still present in rails 4, set it to true in development, and open browser console, check for status codes of css, js files. If it is 304 that means it's loading from cache.

Comment: How do you check status code for css and js files in the console?

Comment: If you are in chrome, right click and click on inspect element, then go to network's tab, reload your webpage, there you will be able to see all the js, css files with their status codes.